# Change Apache DocumentRoot base on page url

Tags: virtualhost

Scenario:

I have a http://www.example.com/ and I want my new project to be accessed via http://www.example.com/new.

Here's what I tried:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/old/public/

Alias /new "/var/www/html/old/new/public/" # -> I tried
```

The problem with this is it's only working on http://www.example.com/new but if I access another page like http://www.example.com/new/page1 it's looking for the routing in the old project.

**.htaccess** on document root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here's the Nginx version, unfortunately the server I'm working with is Apache so I need to convert this into Apache vhost

```
location ^~ /new {
    alias "/var/www/html/old/new/public/";

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /new/index.php?$query_string last;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the down vote, care to comment so I can learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual of the [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) directive

> Note that if you include a trailing <kbd>/</kbd> on the URL-path then the server will require a trailing <kbd>/</kbd> in order to expand the alias. That is, if you use
>
> ```
> Alias "/icons/" "/usr/local/apache/icons/"
> ```
>
> then the URL /icons will not be aliased, as it lacks that trailing <kbd>/</kbd> Likewise, **if you omit the slash on the URL-path then you must also omit it from the file-path**.

So you either have a trailing <kbd>/</kbd> to few or too many in your current setup...

Try either

```
Alias /new /var/www/html/old/new/public
```

or

```
Alias /new/ /var/www/html/old/new/public/
```

Comment: Didn't work. I tried both of them. :(

Comment: Do your log files tell you anything then? And you don't have `.htaccess` files or absolute paths in your code either?

Comment: I don't think log files will help me with this one because my goal is to make sure when I access the /new/* the doc root should stay on the new project. But I do have .htaccess in the doc root. Please see updates in my question.

Comment: You hint about the .htaccess solved my problem! Thank you!